# Code Signing required 'WatchKit Extension' in SDK 'watchOS 3.2'

Tags: ios10, provisioning-profile, ios-app-extension, bundle-identifier

I have migrated watchOS 1 to watchOS 2. So I had to change the extension Bundle id with a prefix from

```
App                my.app.com                       
Watch              my.app.com.watchkit                  
Watch Extension    my.app.com.watchkit.extension // old one was -> my.app.com.extension
```

After updating the bundle id I am getting an error like this when trying to upload to the App Store on Fastlane.

```
Provisioning profile "app-distribution-provision" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement.
Code signing is required for product type 'WatchKit Extension' in SDK 'watchOS 3.2'
```

I also created a new `.mobileprovision` for Watch Extension and added it to XCode. However I am still getting this error when trying to upload App Store. Do Should I update .p12 file? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed the bundle identifier of the Watch Extension, you also need to update the bundle identifier in the Entitlements file for the Extension. You can see the location of the entitlement file in Build Settings under "Code Signing Entitlements".